# UITextView caret position goes upwords

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, caret

I have a UITextView inside UIViewController as subview. When I tap inside the textview, the caret somethimes jumps upwards. After beginning of typing, everything is ok, but when I delete all text it always jumps up again.

Here you can see problem:

[image: Caret problem]

I have tried:

`self.textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;`

and

`self.textView.scrollEnabled = NO;`

But problem was still here. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: try textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0

Comment: Tried now, and this does not working